# Проблемы с Json C#

Tags: c#, json, wpf, json.net, newtonsoft.json

Знаю что есть куча подобных вопросов, но к сожалению не смог на их примере исправить ошибку у меня.

Выбрал json файл в качестве формата для хранения введенных данных пользователем. он выглядит след. образом:

```
[{"login": "", "password": "", "steam_id": "", "in_list": "", "api_key": ""}, {"login": "", "password": "", "steam_id": "", "in_list": "", "api_key": ""}]
```

Внутри "" лежат данные соответственно и таких элементов много(в примере оставил 2)

Классы с описанием элементов:

```
namespace Controll_prjct
{

    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public string login { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string steam_id { get; set; }
        public string in_list { get; set; }
        public string api_key { get; set; }
    }

}
```

То как я пытаюсь достать данные из json файла:

```
string jsonFile = File.ReadAllText(@"path to file");

Class1 data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1>(jsonFile);
Console.WriteLine(data);
```

Ну и ошибка соответственно:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Elysium_prjct.Class1' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1."
```

Я и мои мешки под глазами будем очень благодарны если поможете исправить ошибку!

Если еще объясните почему, то отдельный поклон.

Comment: Вы в объект присваеваете массив

Comment: Читайте ошибку, там ведь внятно сказано что и как, а также внимательно следуйте структуре JSON, она очень простая. Вот смотрите `[ ... ]` - это массив/коллекция, `{ .... }` - это класс, который содержит в себе нужные свойства, `"..." : ... ` - это свойство, где первое имя, а второе значение, ну а дальше идет комбинация этого всего, например `{ "AAA": { "Value" : 13 } }` - первым идет `{}`, значит это класс, далее идет `"AAA" : {...}` - в классе свойство с названием AAA и типом класс, `"Value" : 13` - свойство с названием Value, типом int. Как видите, все элементарно.

Comment: Исходя из этого, смотрим теперь на ваш JSON, начинается он с `[]` - значит это массив/коллекция, внутри этих скобок у вас идет `{}` - это класс. В итоге получаем `Class1[]` или `List<Class1>` это ваша стартовая точка JSON, а не просто класс, или `Rootobject`. Ну и ошибку читайте, вам пишет `Не могу array преобразовать в Class1 на строке 1, позиции 1`.

Comment: `Class1[] data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1[]>(jsonFile);`

Comment: Спасибо огромное за объяснение @EvgeniyZ Евгений
Очень благодарен за прямую подсказку  aepot

Ошибка ушла, однако в консоль выдает значение Controll.Class1[], а это явно не то что лежит в json. 
прошу прощения за такие банальные вопросы, я пришел с питона, где это все делается в одну строчку и даже представить не мог, что с такой банальной задачей провожусь целый день.

Comment: Действительно банальная. Вот представьте у вас есть корзинка яблок, вам надо вес каждого яблока записать на листочек, вы берете и тупо на лист ставите всю корзину, в надежде что там само каким-либо образом запишется, а не берете каждое яблоко, взвешиваете, берете вес, записываете, и так далее. Вот у вас сейчас аналогично с выводом, где у вас есть коллекция классов `Class1[]`, из которой вам надо вывести что-то, но вместо этого вы тупо делаете `Console.WriteLine(Class1[])`, ну вот вам и вывело стандартно, а именно тип того, что передали.

Comment: @СашкаБоров в классе напишите `public override ToString() { return $"login: {login}, steam_id: {steam_id}"; }` и цикл `foreach (var item in data) Console.WriteLine(item);`. По умолчанию C# не знает, как ваши собственные классы выводить, он умеет строки, числа, другие примитивы, но как выводить комплексные объекты - решаеть только вам.

Comment: Есть конечно в C# структура, которая сама может себя отформатирвоать в строку, `record` называется, но поддерживается начиная с C# 9, а судя по тому что у здесь JSON.NET, то у вас какой-то старый фреймворк. Иначе не вижу причин не использовать встроенный System.Text.Json вместо старичка Newtonsoft'а.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Очень приятно осознавать, что есть люди которые готовы помочь даже с такими простыми задачами. Активно изучаю c#, ваш вклад в мое образование будет не напрасен, я вам обещаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку в JSON файле находится массив объектов попробуйте изменить свой код десереализации на следующий:

`List<Class1> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class1>>(jsonFile);`

Для вывода элементов массива можете воспользоваться циклом в данном случае вполне подойдет `foreach`:

```
foreach(var element in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

По-умолчанию метод `ToString()` у типа `List` выводит название типа. Поэтому лучше выводить поэлементно. При этом в классе Class1 необходимо будет переопределить метод `ToString()`. Ещё как вариант в цикле выводить все поля отдельно, т. е. `Console.WriteLine(element.login);`

Надеюсь это поможет.

Answer (score -1):

```
Rootobject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonFile);
```

Comment: Потому, что в файле лежит не Class1, а массив Class1, то есть Rootobject

Comment: уже пробовал, ошибка вся та же

Comment: `Rootobject`? А если на JSON внимательнее посмотреть? Там нет объекта никакого снаружи,это же просто массив, а ни какой не объект. Ответ неправильный.